# PHP, MYSQL + javascript? to produce a result (price) based on three user SELECT inputs

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm very new (one month) into coding and using MySQL, PHP, and (just started last night) Javascript.  I am trying to find a code example to do the following:

a) User uses a drop list (SELECT) to choose a product (say a hotel).
b) Same user also uses a second drop list (SELECT) to choose the related time period (different rates weekends vs. weekdays for example).
c) finally, user selects the room type.

assuming availability (got that part figured), the three inputs have an inpact on the price result (which I would like to calculate based on these user inputs).

**For example:**
input a) Hotel California (yes, the Eagles song is playing right now)
input b) March 23, 2012
input c) a 1 bedroom Suite

I know I need to use Java to do this next part which is to have it update totals on the same page as the user adds rooms and options (breakfast, etc).

Anyone's help is, in advance, much appreciated (even if just a link to a relevant example).

*** AS an update in response to a comment, yes, I definitely would want the price to update through the server and post/fetch to/from MySQL dbase to PHP to the screen.

Comment: Do. Not. Use. Javascript. Not to calculate the price. Do this serverside I beg you. Or sleep in your hotel for 1 cent. You choose.

On a related note: try looking at AJAX requests.

Comment: Hmmm, so that's how the hiring process works nowadays? Interesting. I think I'll apply to a rocket scientist position after reading some books on fuel combustion and lighting up fireworks for a month.

Comment: hiring process?  No, developing a dbase for my business.   As for teaching one's self ... do you mean as in Thomas Jefferson, pythagorous, Robert Goddard (rocket scientist that invented modern rocketry) or people, such as myself, whom have a zeal for learning new technologies?

Comment: For the record, I've purchased programs (some customized) in the past to do what I am attempting.  None could perform the tasks I desired; so, I developed an excel spreadsheet that could do all I am atempting except interface, conveniently, with the web.  (And, yes, I read a few books on Excel over the years and taught myself with significant mastery to impress those with signifigant codie background and have them ask me to demonstrate at seminars).  Your skillset in life is limited only by you imagination and belief in yourself.  I only ask assistance in getting me on the next path. Thanks

Comment: No offense, but "mastering" Excel is roughly equivalent to mastering building with LEGO and venturing into civil engineering. I don't mean to be a dick, but if you want to learn real programming, start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously you're going to have to have your own databases but here's an example version of the code(the PHP side) since yous seem to be able to do the javascript side on your own.

```
<?PHP 
//we're checking if they posted anything since I think you're going to include this on the same page, if not it's still a good check to avoid overhead.
if($_POST){
//The $_POST variable is all data that is being posted by the client. It's an associative array, and I've taken liberty of naming the "name" field on various inputs(the select) on this side.
    $db_password='your_database_users_password';
    $db_username='your_database_users_username';
    $db_host='your databases host(likely localhost)';
    //if you're using php 5.3+ use mysqli_connect, if below that, use mysql_connect and use mysql_ functions
    $connection=mysqli_connect($db_password,$db_username,$db_host);
    mysqli_select_db($conn,'hotel_database');
    //if you're going to have users to have a special rate on certain dates e.g. holidays, you're going to have to code that up, later.This is just a very very basic one.
    $query="SELECT room_rate FROM room_info WHERE hotel=".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['hotel_name']);
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($connection,$result)){
        $room_rate=$row['room_rate];
    }
    $days_spent=$_POST['time_staying_end']-$_POST['time_staying_start'];
    $cost=$days_spent*$room_rate;
    echo $cost;
?>
```

And that's the code on the serverside. It's pretty simplified but it does what it should. If you're wanting more information about it then I'd check the [PHP manual on mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) They'll have a lot more information about what to do and where in there.

Escape all user input, the easiest way if it's a string is to just use the mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$unsafe_input);
or if it's supposed to be an integer use intval($unsafe_numerical_value);

OK then, since the person who asked this question asked some more information about it. You're going to want to do it via ajax. If you have jquery installed(which is what I use) it's going to be a lot easier. It'll be something like this.

```
//as you can see, you want to seperate your posted variables with an &.
var posts='hotel_name='+$('hotel_name_identifier').val()+'&start_date='+$('start_date').val()+'&end_date='+$('end_date).val();
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"the_page_containing_your_sql_code.php",
        data:posts,
        dataType:"json", //I chose JSON since it's the best format for sending data
        success:function (datum){ //you need this to handle your returned data
            use_data(datum);
        }
    }
```

for more information about it. go here.[jquery Ajax api documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I really need to watch my code more than just typing things quickly to get the code done. It's safe now.

Comment: It happens.. can understand :)

Comment: The worst part about this, is that I escape everything, sanitize everything, and do everything to make sure that nothing gets past me. And on stack overflow, trying to help someone. I end up posting code that could lead to horrible horrible things. Just glad you were there to catch me. I'd have likely just moved on.

Comment: Actually the PHP + MySQL I understood fairly well; it's the form [in javascript] to have the select (drop lists) interact with the PHP/MySQL that I am fuzzy on writing and most new at understanding.  HOWEVER, your PHP suggestion above did trigger a few good thoughts about my approach.